# Using Lists/Pattern Matching in SML/NJ

Tags: sml

I'm having trouble with pattern matching with lists in SML. I'm trying to create a function that takes a 2x2 real matrix (defined as `'a list list`) and creates a complex `(real * real)`. The matrix is formatted as a list of lists(that are made with reals) with each list being a row. I know that I have to pattern match but I'm unsure how to implement my understanding into actual code. My code thus far is:

```
fun fromMatrix ((a::M):real matrix) : complex =  (hd a, tl M);
```

I keep getting this error:

```
stdIn:1.5-13.32 Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [tycon mismatch]
  expression:  real * real list list
  result type:  complex
  in declaration:
    fromMatrix =
      (fn <pat> :: <pat> : real matrix => (hd <exp>,tl <exp>): complex)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so if `(a::M)` has type `real matrix` (or `real list list`), then that means `a` (head) has type `real list` and `M` (tail) has type `real list list`. Then `hd a` has type `real`, and `tl M` has type `real list list`. So putting them together, `(hd a, tl M)` has type `real * real list list`, probably not what you want.

You probably want to understand that for lists, `x :: y` means that `x` is the first element, and `y` is the rest of the list (not the second element), which is a list. Similarly, the `hd` function returns the first element of a list, and the `tl` function returns the rest of the list. If you want to extract the first two elements, you could use the pattern `x :: y :: z` (where `z` is the rest of the list after the first 2 elements). If you know it's going to be a 2-element list, you could match `x :: y :: []`, or equivalently, `[x, y]`. You can nest patterns, so if you have a 2-element list of 2-element lists, you could directly match `[[a, b], [c, d]]`. However, using a fixed-size list is a sign of bad design. You probably want to use a tuple instead.

Comment: yeah i didn't realize i was using the infix notation wrong. thanks!